# JSF <p:calendar> widget is not refreshed when selecting different month

Tags: java, jsf, primefaces, calendar

Here is my code for a calendar widget using primefaces.

```
<p:column width="100">
                    <f:facet name="header">
                        <h:outputText value="Date uploaded" />
                    </f:facet>
    <p:calendar   value="#{dets.dttcpuploadprism}" pattern="MM/dd/yyyy"  mindate="#{dets.date1}" maxdate="#{dets.systemdate}"  readonlyInput="true" size="10" navigator="true" >
                        <p:ajax event="click"  process="@this"  partialSubmit="true"
                            listener="#{Bean.setCompilanceButton}"
                            update=":showdataForm:cat2 :showdataForm:dataDisplay    :growl :error" />
                        <f:attribute name="index" value="_#{rowIndex}" />    </p:calendar> </p:column >
```

Backing bean code for hte Ajax event metioned above is 
Its not having much code in in.

```
public void setCompilanceButton(AjaxBehaviorEvent event) {

        int index = Integer.parseInt(((String) event.getComponent()
                .getAttributes().get("index")).replace("_", ""));
        System.out.println("Index:\t" + index);

        if (list!= null) {
            selectedModel = list.get(index);
        }

        if (selectedModel != null) {
            if (selectedModel.getDtcompilanceappr() != null
                    && selectedModel.getDttcpuploadprism() == null) {

                slcomp= "DisApprove";
            }
        }

    }
```

Issue:

There is date1,date2 & date3 inside the datatable.
Afer providing the date1 the date2 should be date2>=date1 and date2<=systemdate.
Hence,I have provided the mindate="#{dets.date1}" maxdate="#{dets.systemdate}"  .

My problem is, if I provide the current month date for date1 the calendar widget is showing the date1 to current system date.
But if I select the date1 as previous month say any date in "feb'14" the calendar is not refreshing the dates for feb month in the calendar widget.

Please find the screen shot provided below
[image]

Though, I have provided the date1 as 02/15/2014 the next date where the calendar widget is enabled is showing the march date correctly.But when I select the feb month in the drop down the dates are not getting refreshed.
How to resolve this issue ? Is it the problem with the widget itself ? Please advise.

Comment: you use prime-faces component??
then try this...
<p:ajax event="dateSelect"....>

Comment: I am suppose to select only one row to save the record in the datatable.When I use the "dateselect" event when I select a row and give the date2 and when i selec another row and provide the same date2 the previously provided date in the previously selected row  is not getting cleared.It remains as it is.

Comment: check the scope of managed bean. `@RequestScoped` or `@ViewScoped` .
try using this

Comment: I am using @ManagedBean,@ViewScoped public class Bean

Comment: No!.It doesn't work in that way too.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/48952/discussion-between-techy360-and-ajay-patel)